# Symfony2 url rewrite in controller/router/htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, url, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if this is supposed to be done in the htaccess, which I'm not good at since I've lived a life on WordPress for too long. But I'm trying to turn a League of Legends summoner name, for examle using WildTurtle's. From this:

http://mobame.com/player/Turtle%20the%20Cat

into this:

http://mobame.com/player/Turtle+the+Cat

How do I go about this?

Comment: What have you done yet? What exactly you mean by changing the URL? It seems just changing the URL encoding type

Comment: @Javad The example is already there above you. I'm trying to make the url less messy and easier for a user to type in the summoner name.